# grails -reloading run-app fails to run a Grails up throwing the following error

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I'm using Grails 2.3.0 on Java 1.6.0_30

```
2014-05-12 15:21:49,378 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodGetDeclaredAnnotations(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:935)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodGetAnnotations(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1491)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-05-12 15:21:49,386 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-05-12 15:21:49,387 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-05-12 15:21:49,387 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to `Grails 2.3.8` yet?

Comment: Is it an empty project? Any plugins for grails? Can you provide more details?

Comment: @saw303 we're using 2.3.0

Comment: @MeIr it used to work and it works without the `-reloading` option. But when I try to run it on Intellij and STS( which probably have `-reloading` by default) it fails.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel means you cannot upgrade and have to stay on 2.3.0?

Comment: @saw303 can give it a try on my local machine. But can't make a change on a team project at this point... Do you think it's necessary?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel they provided lots of bug fixes since `Grails 2.3.0`. Maintenance upgrades from `2.3.0` to `2.3.x` usually do not break your project. Go have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrade to the latest `2.3.8` version of Grails.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to run `grails clean` and then try again.

Comment: Next I would try: go to ~/.grails and remove all cache and other things that have been downloaded. Then clean and run. It will re-download all the dependencies -- sometimes it helps.

Comment: It seems like it is code related. The only thing I would try without looking into code is what @saw303 suggested - try different grails versions like 2.3.8.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel Did try you delete your `target` directory?

Answer (score 0):

[Download](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar or latest. Put in in grails dir. Run grails with following commands

```
set GRAILS_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -javaagent:springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true  
grailsw -no-reloading run-app
```

Note: -no-reloading is to disable default reloading springloaded. It will wirk fine with reloading

Comment: It worked with no reloading. I want it to work with reloading enabled.

Comment: It would work with reloading. It's just setting for disable default springloaded and force to use newest springloaded which is responsible for reloading.